# How to set n-th character in UTF-8 string?

Tags: php, string, character

In order to get n-th character you can write:

```
mb_substr($s,$n,1);
```

but how to set n-th character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so:

```
$s = 'hello';
$n = 2; // first l
$r = 'x'; // replace with x
echo mb_substr($s, 0, $n) . $r . mb_substr($s, $n + 1);
```

Comment: Ah, manual way :-) Thank you. Now I wonder if it is possible to speed it up (UTF-8 handling is expensive, and get uses one call while set would use two).